# What is the difference between DotNetOpenAuth and Owin.Security?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

I want to create a website that can accept multi-Login (google or facebook) by `asp.net mvc`.

When I create the website, I found the file in the App_Start have two kind of strategy.

One is using `DotNetOpenAuth`, and the other is using `Owin.Security`.

So, I want to know the difference between `DotNetOpenAuth` and `Owin.Security`.

Which one is better ?

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32243661/dotnetopenauth-vs-owin-oauth/44975158)