# DotNetOpenAuth vs Owin OAuth

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin, dotnetopenauth

I am new the webAPI2, so please excuse me if my question is trivial. I want to implement token based security for my webAPI, so that other applications (apart from my SPA) can also call my webAPIs.

I started with Owin OpenAuth and implemented a POC. Everything worked well. But when I had to send client to Authorization to Authorization server, I could not find any inbuilt function to do that. I had to build this my self. Then I came across DotNetOpenAuth that provides APIs to set the communication as well. As far as I could find out, Microsoft is favoring Owin OpenAuth over DotNetOpenAuth.

Can anybody please provide the differences between these two? Also, which one is recommended?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

Brock Allen answered a similar question [here](https://forums.asp.net/post/5880121.aspx)

> The OWIN middleware is grated more for just the protocol bits, but has
>   none of the necessary persistence bits (or replay protection or
>   refresh token support or many other things). If you are interested in
>   working directly with the protocol because you want to learn it and
>   really learn how to build a server, then the OWIN middleware is an ok
>   place to start. But if all you want is a sever that already has all of
>   those pieces implemented, then consider looking into IdentityServer

or DotnetOpenAuth